# Auto correction is good or not?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I'm kind of confused that should I use an auto-correction when I am codding with Html, CSS, and JavaScript. Sometimes it is helpful but I feel I learn less??

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is not suitable for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Opposite, auto correction including function padding and etc is very helpful for people that are just learning language or framework and for people that are experienced. You waste too much time reading docs for each framework just to know which arguments some specific function takes when you can use an IDE and it will do all the work for you.